# Creating a derived parameter from sims.list within jags model

Tags: r, bayesian, jags

I am working on a combined integrated model/population viability analysis in jags, and am trying to create a derived parameter to use in my population projections.

In the current version of the model that runs without errors, I have time-dependent survival parameters that are generated within the capture-mark-recapture portion of the model, and feed into the population state-space model for the years I have data for `(t in 1:n.occasions-1)`. I have created derived parameters based on the mean of these parameters, that I have used in my population state-space model for the years I would like to project over `(t in n.occasion:n.occasions-1+K)`. However, by using this approach, I think the variance around the mean of the derived parameters is too small and is affecting my predicted population sizes.

As such, I would like to try creating a derived parameter that is a random draw from the sims.list for the time-dependent survival parameters, to capture the variance better. My question essentially, is can you draw from the sims list of a model, within the model itself? Or can you only draw from that sims list once the model has finished running?

In terms of what I have tried and the errors I receive:

I have tried creating a derived parameter, and get a syntax error near "$", relating to the line where I reference the sims.list.

My model is over 3000 lines long, so I have included an example of a simpler model below, where I have tried to do the same thing, and receive the same error (E`rror in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :  3 nodes produced errors; first error:  Error parsing model file: syntax error on line 103 near "$`), to illustrate the issue I am facing. The model code I am using is courtesy of Michael Schaub and Marc Kery from their IPM Book. In this example, I have created the derived parameter sj.f, which I am using to replace sj[t] in the part of the population model that predicts into the future.

This is my first question on stackoverflow (and second attempt at posting, this time with a reproducible example), so apologies if I have included too little or too much information.

```
# Load woodchat shrike data and produce data overview
library(IPMbook)
data(woodchat10)
str(woodchat10)

K <- 15    # Number of forecast years
jags.data <- list(marr.j=woodchat10$marr.j, marr.a=woodchat10$marr.a, n.occasions=ncol(woodchat10$marr.j), rel.j=rowSums(woodchat10$marr.j), rel.a=rowSums(woodchat10$marr.a), J=woodchat10$J, B=woodchat10$B, count=woodchat10$count, pNinit=dUnif(1, 50), K=K)
str(jags.data)


K <- 15    # Number of forecast years
jags.data <- list(marr.j=woodchat10$marr.j, marr.a=woodchat10$marr.a, n.occasions=ncol(woodchat10$marr.j), rel.j=rowSums(woodchat10$marr.j), rel.a=rowSums(woodchat10$marr.a), J=woodchat10$J, B=woodchat10$B, count=woodchat10$count, pNinit=dUnif(1, 50), K=K)
str(jags.data)


# Write JAGS model file
cat(file="model1.txt", "
model { 
# Priors and linear models
mean.logit.sj <- logit(mean.sj)
mean.sj ~ dunif(0, 1) 
mean.logit.sa <- logit(mean.sa)
mean.sa ~ dunif(0, 1) 
mean.p ~ dunif(0, 1)
mean.log.f <- log(mean.f)
mean.f ~ dunif(0, 10)

for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){
  p[t] <- mean.p
}

for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1+K)){  # Here we extend the loop to K more years
  logit.sj[t] <- mean.logit.sj + eps.sj[t]
  eps.sj[t] ~ dnorm(0, tau.sj)
  sj[t] <- ilogit(logit.sj[t])
  logit.sa[t] <- mean.logit.sa + eps.sa[t]
  eps.sa[t] ~ dnorm(0, tau.sa)
  sa[t] <- ilogit(logit.sa[t])
}

for (t in 1:(n.occasions+K)){   # Extended loop also here
  log.f[t] <- mean.log.f + eps.f[t]
  eps.f[t] ~ dnorm(0, tau.f)
  f[t] <- exp(log.f[t])
}

sigma.sj ~ dunif(0, 10)
tau.sj <- pow(sigma.sj, -2)
sigma.sa ~ dunif(0, 10)
tau.sa <- pow(sigma.sa, -2)
sigma.f ~ dunif(0, 10)
tau.f <- pow(sigma.f, -2)

sigma ~ dunif(0.5, 50)
tau <- pow(sigma, -2)

# Population count data (state-space model)
# Model for the initial population size: uniform priors
N[1,1] ~ dcat(pNinit)
N[2,1] ~ dcat(pNinit)

# Process model over time: our model of population dynamics
for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){  # Note extended loop
  N[1,t+1] ~ dpois(sj[t] * f[t] * (N[1,t] + N[2,t])) 
  N[2,t+1] ~ dbin(sa[t], (N[1,t] + N[2,t]))
}

for (t in n.occasions:(n.occasions-1+K)){  # Note extended loop
  N[1,t+1] ~ dpois(sj.f * f[t] * (N[1,t] + N[2,t])) 
  N[2,t+1] ~ dbin(sa[t], (N[1,t] + N[2,t]))
}

# Observation model
for (t in 1:n.occasions){
  count[t] ~ dnorm(N[1,t] + N[2,t], tau)
}

# Productivity data (Poisson regression model)
for (t in 1:n.occasions){
  J[t] ~ dpois(f[t] * B[t])
}

# Capture-recapture data (CJS model with multinomial likelihood)
# Define the multinomial likelihood
for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){
  marr.j[t,1:n.occasions] ~ dmulti(pr.j[t,], rel.j[t])
  marr.a[t,1:n.occasions] ~ dmulti(pr.a[t,], rel.a[t])
}
# Define the cell probabilities of the m-arrays
# Main diagonal
for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){
  q[t] <- 1-p[t]   # Probability of non-recapture
  pr.j[t,t] <- sj[t] * p[t]
  pr.a[t,t] <- sa[t] * p[t]
  # Above main diagonal
  for (j in (t+1):(n.occasions-1)){
    pr.j[t,j] <- sj[t] * prod(sa[(t+1):j]) * prod(q[t:(j-1)]) * p[j]
    pr.a[t,j] <- prod(sa[t:j]) * prod(q[t:(j-1)]) * p[j]
  } #j
  # Below main diagonal
  for (j in 1:(t-1)){
    pr.j[t,j] <- 0
    pr.a[t,j] <- 0
  } #j
} #t
# Last column: probability of non-recapture
for (t in 1:(n.occasions-1)){
  pr.j[t,n.occasions] <- 1-sum(pr.j[t,1:(n.occasions-1)])
  pr.a[t,n.occasions] <- 1-sum(pr.a[t,1:(n.occasions-1)])
}

# Derived parameters
# Total population size
for (t in 1:(n.occasions+K)){
  Ntot[t] <- N[1,t] + N[2,t]
}

# Random draw of survival from 1 to n.occassions-1
sj.f <- sample(out1$sims.list$sj, 1)

# Check whether the population is extinct in the future
for (t in 1:K){
  extinct[t] <- equals(Ntot[n.occasions+t], 0)  
}
} # end model
")

# Initial values
inits <- function(){list(mean.sj=runif(1, 0, 0.5), mean.sa=runif(1, 0.4, 0.6), mean.f=runif(1, 1.3, 2))}

# Parameters monitored
parameters <- c("mean.sj", "sigma.sj", "mean.sa", "sigma.sa", "mean.p", "mean.f", "sigma.f", "sigma", "sj", "sa", "f", "N", "Ntot", "extinct")

# MCMC settings
ni <- 20000; nb <- 5000; nc <- 3; nt <- 3; na <- 1000

# Call JAGS (ART 1 min), check convergence and summarize posteriors
out1 <- jags(jags.data, inits, parameters, "model1.txt", n.iter=ni, n.burnin=nb, n.chains=nc, n.thin=nt, n.adapt=na, parallel=TRUE)
```

Comment: I've used JAGS several times, but I am by no means an expert.  It's not clear which package you're using to interface with JAGS.  Nevertheless, I suspect you *can't* do what you are trying to do.  I say this because (1) The line causing your error is `sj.f <- sample(out1$sims.list$sj, 1)`.  (2) `out1` appears to be an R object.  As such it's not available to JAGS.  (3) there's no reference to a function named `sample` in the JAGS user manual, though there is a `sample` function in R - again, are you referencing an R function in your JAGS model?  That's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can randomly draw from the vector of time-dependent survival parameters, but not by sampling from the `sims.list` object. As @Limey pointed out in the comment above, `out1$sims.list` is an R object that's not accessible to JAGS and `sample` is an R function not mentioned in the [user manual](https://people.stat.sc.edu/hansont/stat740/jags_user_manual.pdf). Here are the steps:

1. Define a vector of the probabilities for each outcome (probability density function): length `n.occasions-1`, each with probability `1/(n.occasions-1)`.
2. Use the categorical distribution, `dcat`, to randomly sample the density above.
3. Use the random samples as indices to draw samples from the time-dependent survival parameters.

Code:

```
# Random draw of survival from 1 to n.occassions-1
punif <- rep(1/(n.occasions-1),(n.occasions-1))
b ~ dcat(punif[])
sj.f <- sj[b]
```

The solution uses [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154530/jags-choosing-a-random-subset-of-a-vector), the `rep` function on page 41 of the [JAGS v4.3.0 user manual](https://people.stat.sc.edu/hansont/stat740/jags_user_manual.pdf), and the `dcat` distribution on page 50 of the user manual (also see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49149/categorical-distribution-in-jags)).

I could also imagine an alternative solution to this problem. Instead of sampling directly from the estimated time-dependent survival parameters (which are coming from observed years, I think?), you could simulate `sj.f` from the distribution for survival and introduce a parameter to examine the influence of variability around mean survival. Instead of the lines above, you could test the below, and explore different values for `eps`.

```
# Random draw of survival from 1 to n.occassions-1    
logit.sj.f <- mean.logit.sj + eps.sj.f
eps.sj.f ~ dnorm(0, tau.sj+eps)
sj.f <- ilogit(logit.sj.f)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestions. The first solution works in the simplified model I posted in the question. However, I can’t get it to work in my actual model. In this model, instead of the parameter sj.f, I have the following indexed parameter: phi.RI.ad[t,1] and phi.RI.ad[t,2]. I’ve tried to create a derived parameters for phi.RI.ad.f by sampling the probability density function of phi.RI.ad[t,1] but can’t get the below to work:

`punif <- rep(1/(n.occasions-1),(n.occasions-1))
b ~ dcat(punif[])
f.phi.RI.ad <- (phi.RI.ad[ ,1])[b]`

Comment: What kind of an error do you get? And what are the dimensions of `phi.RI.ad` - my guess is you would need it to have `b` rows and `2` columns?  I'm also not sure if JAGS allows you to select one column from a matrix and then sample from it as if it were a vector (`f.phi.RI.ad <- (phi.RI.ad[ ,1])[b]`). You might try the following: `f.phi.RI.ad <- phi.RI.ad[b,1]`.